# Liferay cluster with SAN storage with ext3

Tags: cluster, storage-area-network, ext3, liferay

I'm deploying an liferay portal in a cluster which has 2 node load balanced, and config both to access to the same data location in a SAN storage devide. The problem is each node can not see the other changing, i.e when node 1 add new image, node 2 can not find this image without mounting the san devide.
So, any one ever successfully deployed a cluster like this. 
I've found one solution is GFS2, but I want to use ext3, because it very simple.
Thanks!

Comment: With complex requirements like this, you are going to have to come to terms with learning a few complex technologies.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? My answer was quite clear the first time you asked about this.

Comment: Sorry! I just check again for my choice before asking other question. The result of using ext3 is that I'm new in clustering and GFS2 is complex. I had some problems with this file system. I posted it at http://serverfault.com/questions/533470/ccs-tool-addnode-and-addfence-error-invalid-option-c.  
Can you help me, please!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a shared block device with a non-cluster filesystem without data corruption. Either use a storage backend that is accessible with e.g. NFS from both nodes or invest the work to set up a cluster file system.